# Expectation of binomial distribution

Tags: probability

From my understanding for a random variable $X \sim Binom (n,p)$, $E(X)=n \times p$, correct?

I was looking at an example problem:

Every pair of the $n$ people is friends with probability $p$. What is $E(X)$? $X$= number of friendships.

$X\sim Binom (\binom{n}{2}, p)$ and $E(X)=\binom{n}{2}p$.

This makes perfect sense. However I got confused by the next part:

What is $E(Y)$, where $Y$= number of friendship triangles?

And the answer is $E(Y)=\binom{n}{3}p^{3}$. However, I don't understand why the $p$ is cubed?

Comment: Imagine three people, A, B, and C. For all three pairs (AB, AC, BC) to be friends, you need three friendships, each with probability $p$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Friendships are like edges in a graph. There is just one edge that connects two vertices, three edges connecting three vertices.

In general, there are $n(n-1)/2$ edges in a complete graph with $n$ vertices (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph)), so there is $2(2-1)/2=1$ edge when $n=2$, there are $3(3-1)/2=3$ edges when $n=3$, etc.

If $p$ is the probability of one edge, the probability of $n(n-1)/2$ (independent) edges is $p^{n(n-1)/2)}$.

Answer (score 0):

I might be stating the obvious / not answering the question, but because every triangle needs to consist of three pairs (hence cube) of friends? hence you are looking for number of unique combinations that are made up of three pairs.